# How to scrape RottenTomatoes Audience Reviews using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm creating a spider using scrapy to scrape Details from rottentomatoes.com. As the search page is rendered dynamically, I used the rottentomatoes API for eg:https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/search?q=inception to get the search results and URL. Following the URL via scrapy, I was able to extract the tomatometer score, audience score, director, cast etc. However, I want to extract all the audience reviews too. The issue is that, audience reviews page (https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception/reviews?type=user) works using pagination and I'm not able to extract data from next page, moreover I couldn't find a way to use the API to extract the details either. Could anyone help me on this.

```
    def parseRottenDetail(self, response):
    print("Reached Tomato Parser")
    try:
        if MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse <= MoviecrawlSpider.total_results:
            items = TomatoCrawlerItem()
            MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse]['tomatometerScore'] = response.css(
                '.mop-ratings-wrap__row .mop-ratings-wrap__half .mop-ratings-wrap__percentage::text').get().strip()
            MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse][
                'tomatoAudienceScore'] = response.css(
                '.mop-ratings-wrap__row .mop-ratings-wrap__half.audience-score .mop-ratings-wrap__percentage::text').get().strip()
            MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse][
                'tomatoCriticConsensus'] = response.css('p.mop-ratings-wrap__text--concensus::text').get()
            if MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse]["type"] == "Movie":
                MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse]['Director'] = response.xpath(
                    "//ul[@class='content-meta info']/li[@class='meta-row clearfix']/div[contains(text(),'Directed By')]/../div[@class='meta-value']/a/text()").get()
            else:
                MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse]['Director'] = response.xpath(
                    "//div[@class='tv-series__series-info-castCrew']/div/span[contains(text(),'Creator')]/../a/text()").get()
            reviews_page = response.css('div.mop-audience-reviews__view-all a[href*="reviews"]::attr(href)').get()
            if len(reviews_page) != 0:
                yield response.follow(reviews_page, callback=self.parseRottenReviews)
            else:
                for key in MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse].keys():
                    if "pageURL" not in key and "type" not in key:
                        items[key] = MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse][key]
                yield items
                if MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse <= MoviecrawlSpider.total_results:
                    MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse += 1
                    print("Parse Values are Current Parse " + str(
                        MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse) + "and Total Results " + str(MoviecrawlSpider.total_results))
                    yield response.follow(MoviecrawlSpider.parse_rotten_list[MoviecrawlSpider.current_parse]["pageURL"],
                                          callback=self.parseRottenDetail)
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(e)
        print(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

After this piece of code is executed I reach the page of reviews ie for eg: https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception/reviews?type=user, Hereafter there is a next button and next page is loaded using pagination. So What should be my approach to extract all the reviews?

```
    def parseRottenReviews(self, response):
    print("Reached Rotten Review Parser")
    items = TomatoCrawlerItem()
```

Comment: Really helpful, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

When you go to the next page, you can notice that it uses the previous end cursor value of the page. You can set the `endCursor` with empty string for the first iteration. Also note that you need the movieId for requuesting reviews, this id can be extracted from the json embedded from JS :

```
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception/reviews?type=user")
data = json.loads(re.search('movieReview\s=\s(.*);', r.text).group(1))

movieId = data["movieId"]

def getReviews(endCursor):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/{movieId}/reviews/user",
    params = {
        "direction": "next",
        "endCursor": endCursor,
        "startCursor": ""
    })
    return r.json()

reviews = []
result = {}
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(f"[{i}] request review")
    result = getReviews(result["pageInfo"]["endCursor"] if i != 0  else "")
    reviews.extend([t for t in result["reviews"]])

print(reviews)
print(f"got {len(reviews)} reviews")
```

Note that you can also scrape the html for the first iteration

Comment: I tried this code yesterday and was working completely fine, but today it is throwing an error: "  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'  ". What can be the reason for this? Is it that rotten tomatoes might have blocked my request?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using Scrapy, I was looking for a way to perform this without using the requests module. The approach is the same, but I found that the page https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/inception had an object `root.RottenTomatoes.context.fandangoData` in the `<script>` tag, which had a key "emsId" which had the Id of the movie which is passed to the api to get details. Going through the network tab on each pagination event, I realised that they used startCursor and endCursor to filter results for each page.

```
pattern = r'\broot.RottenTomatoes.context.fandangoData\s*=\s*(\{.*?\})\s*;\s*\n'
                    json_data = response.css('script::text').re_first(pattern)
                    movie_id = json.loads(json_data)["emsId"]
{SpiderClass}.movieId = movie_id
    next_page = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/" + movie_id + "/reviews/user?direction=next&endCursor=&startCursor="
                    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parseRottenReviews)
```

For the first iteration, you could leave the `startCursor` and `endCursor` parameter blank. Now you enter the parse function. You could get the `startCursor` and `endCursor` parameters of the next page from the current response. Repeat this until the `hasNextPage` attribute is false.

```
def parseRottenReviews(self, response):
print("Reached Rotten Review Parser")
current_result = json.loads(response.text)
for review in current_result["reviews"]:
    {SpiderClass}.reviews.append(review) #Spider class memeber So that it could be shared among iterations
if current_result["pageInfo"]["hasNextPage"] is True:
    next_page = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/movie/" + \
                str({SpiderClass}.movieId) + "/reviews/user?direction=next&endCursor=" + str(
        current_result["pageInfo"][
            "endCursor"]) + "&startCursor=" + str(current_result["pageInfo"]["startCursor"])
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parseRottenReviews)
```

Now the `{SpiderClass}.reviews` array will have the reviews